# Navigate to a Page/Component and set as Root that in Ionic4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular4-router, ionic4, router-outlet

I am developing an application in *Ionic4*, I am using `router-outlet` for navigation. I want, when I navigate to a page, I should setup as root Page. Like in *Ionic3*, when we want to set page as root we do following.

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot('PageName');
```

In *Ionic4*, I am navigating like this

```
this.router.navigate(['/path']);
```

also how I can clear the history of last navigated pages in *Ionic4*.

any one can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer to [Ionic 4 setRoot with Angular Router](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51758016/9966041). As per this, *Ionic 4* with *Angular routing*, there is no root page to be defined.